# How can I replace part of a path with a fixed string?

Tags: string, shell, replace, path

I wanna get directory name with minor change from path string in one line.
For example,  if given string is
    `'./dir1/dir2/dir3/xxx.txt'`

I wanna get
    `'./dir1/fix_string_as_suffix'`

And I want to combine it with find command like below though it's not fixed yet.

```
find . -type d \( -name 'vendor' \) -prune -o -type f -name '*.txt' -print | cut -d'/' -f1,2
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'minor change`?

Comment: minor change means, I want to join specific string to result.
'./dir1/fixed_string'

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed`:

```
s='./dir1/dir2/dir3/xxx.txt'
sed -E 's~^(([^/]*/){2}).*~\1~' <<< "$s"

./dir1/
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use IFS & *printf* Builtin

There's more than one way to do what you want within the shell, depending on whether you want to use standard utilities like *cut*, *sed*, or *awk*, or if you want limit yourself to expansions and builtins found within the shell itself. One approach is to split the path into components, and then rejoin them with the *printf* command or builtin. For example:

```
path='./dir1/dir2/dir3/xxx.txt'

IFS='/' read -ra dirs <<< "$path"
printf '%s' "${dirs[0]}/" "${dirs[1]}/" "..." $'\n'
```

If you want to turn this into a one-liner, join the commands with a semicolon and/or use [curly braces for command grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping). However, readability trumps conciseness, especially in shell programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`cut`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(Unix)) command:

```
#!/bin/bash

path="./dir1/dir2/dir3/xxx.txt"
suffix="something fixed string"
prefix=`echo $path | cut -d/ -f1,2`
echo "$prefix/$suffix"
```

Concatenate lines from above using `;` to get it on one line:

```
prefix=`echo $path | cut -d/ -f1,2` ; echo "$prefix/$suffix"
```

Comment: Yes, I did it. But I wanna add minor change to result.
I want to get `./dir1/...` exactly.

Comment: After getting `./dir/`, I wanna join some string to result.
I expect `./dir1/something fixed string`

Comment: Hopefully, I wanna do that in one line.

Comment: @Harry So what do you think?

Comment: I see you've used my `cut` suggestion in your question. So it's working then?

Comment: I've used cut command from the beginning, what I want to know is to join suffix to result in one line because it should be used for result of find command.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's what you look for

```
find . -type d \( -name 'vendor' \) -prune -o -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c 'echo "${1%/*}/fix_string_as_suffix"' fstrasuff {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I ended up as below.

```
find . -type d \( -name 'vendor' \) -prune -o -type f -name '*.txt' -print | cut -d'/' -f1,2 | uniq | awk '{print $1"/..."}'
```